# Unable to install ... Type of message '(ayussass)', does not match expected type '(ayussasass)'

Tags: software-center

I've come across this error when trying to install just about any application from the Ubuntu Software Center.

This is pretty much a new installation of Ubuntu 18.04.

`Type of message '(ayussass)', does not match expected type '(ayussasass)'`

A quick google search for `ayussass` or `ayussasass` pretty much has zero results. So I don't really know how to search for help on this one.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Software Center, specifically related to something called "dbus". I'd suggest submitting a bug report. In the mean time, best option is to install via command-line utility `apt`, or if you do need GUI tool - Synaptic

Comment: no errors from anything I've installed with `apt`

Answer (score 1):

Disable all the plugins in the Ubuntu Software Center if any, you can find the plugin details under the installed software.

Open the Ubuntu Software app. Go in the installed section. Fine the Gnome Software App. Click on it, scroll down until you see Add-ons. See if there are any addons enabled, disable them and it would ask to reload, do that and you should be good to go.